# Sort Code Reuse for Multilingual Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation, sorting

I'm attempting to sort a result from a table that is multilingual. I would like to have the sorting algorithm come from a function but then it adds a 8% hit to the performance, at least. So, I'm not quite sure how to go about it. So, for the sorting I'm using this [method described in an article on how to sort multilingual tables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31194.t-sql-sort-data-by-multiple-languages.aspx) as shown below:

```
select UnicodeData,Collation
from (
    select
        ML.UnicodeData,
        ML.Collation,
        RN =
            CASE
                when Collation = 'he-IL' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by unicodedata Collate Hebrew_CI_AS                  )
                when Collation = 'en-US' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by unicodedata Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  )
                when Collation = 'kn-IN' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by unicodedata Collate Indic_General_100_CI_AS       )
                when Collation = 'hi-IN' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by unicodedata Collate Indic_General_100_CI_AS       )
                when Collation = 'ar-EG' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by unicodedata Collate Arabic_CI_AS                  )
                when Collation = 'cs'    then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by unicodedata Collate Czech_CI_AS                   )
            END
    from MultipleLanguages ML
) T
order by RN
```

Except I abstracted out the `collation` code into its own function, like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [utils].[OrderByLanguage]
( @LanguageID tinyint
, @IDName utils.ID_Name READONLY
) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
SELECT
      t.ID
    , CASE @LanguageID
        WHEN 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.[Name]) -- en
        WHEN 3 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.[Name]) -- en-ca
        WHEN 6 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.[Name]) -- 'en-nz'
        WHEN 5 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.[Name]) -- 'en-za'
        WHEN 2 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.[Name] COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI) -- es
        WHEN 4 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.[Name] COLLATE French_CI_AI) -- 'fr-ca'
    END RowNumber
FROM @IDName t
```

But then when I call this function I have to do this awkward double call on the table-valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION api.GetTable
( @LanguageCode VARCHAR(10)
) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE
          @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)
        , @LangID tinyint
    DECLARE @Sort utils.ID_Name

    SET @LangID = api_utils.GetLanguageID(@LanguageCode)

    INSERT INTO @Sort (ID, [Name])
    SELECT
          t.ID
        , t.title
    FROM api_utils.GetTable(@LangID) t

    SET @Result = (
        SELECT
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.ID) id,
            t.category,
            t.[system],
            t.title,
            JSON_QUERY(utils.ToRawJsonArray((
                SELECT x.[Description]
                FROM api_utils.GetKeywords(t.ID, @LangID) x
                ORDER BY x.[Description]
                FOR JSON AUTO), 'Description')
            ) keywords
        FROM api_utils.GetTable(@LangID) t
        ORDER BY (SELECT s.RowNumber
                  FROM utils.OrderByLanguage(@LangID, @Sort) s
                  WHERE s.ID = t.ID)
        FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('titles')
        )

    RETURN @Result

END
```

So, you can see that I have to call the function `api_utils.GetTable` twice. As far as I can tell the only other way to abstract out the collation sorting would be to put in the actual sorting algorithm and then have a script that searches all the code base and add in another collation language whenever I need to add another language. Is there any other way to do this? What have others done? What would be the best practice? The performance on this isn't absolutely critical but it is nice to keep it lean so doesn't take too long since it is already an intensive call.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Answering @srutzky's questions in comments:

> 1) How much data is returned by api_utils.GetTable?

There's about 150 records returned from the table.

> 2) Why call api_utils.GetTable twice when the first time the result is dumped into @Sort?

The `@Sort` table is a memory optimized user defined table (`UDT`). Since I'm passing a table into the `utils.OrderByLanguage` function it needs to be a `UDT`. Which means I need to get the data from the inline function `api_utils.GetTable` twice. I'm not sure if it caused a performance issue calling `api_utils.GetTable` twice. Maybe `SQL Server` is smart enough to cache the result? Testing it again the `INSERT` query cost is 38%. So, a fairly significant part of the query cost.

> Wouldn't it be faster to add the category and system columns to @Sort and pull them back in the first call and then use @Sort in the FROM clause?

Since the `UDT` is generic for use across all the different procedures that call the function `utils.OrderByLanguage` It would make it very difficult to generalize for an unknown number of columns that the different procedures would use.

> 3) Does this have to be a function or can it be a stored procedure?

Are you talking about `api_utils.GetTable`? I would prefer that `api_utils.GetTable` stay a function as it makes it easier to use and test. Where I call `api_utils.GetTable` it is a `Stored Procedure`.

If you are talking about `utils.OrderByLanguage` I don't mind if it would be a `stored procedure`. I'm not sure how that would help though. So, if it would please let me know!

**Update to Accepted Answer**

I found adding a an index didn't make a difference performance wise. I also figured I might as well put the `sort` column in the original `#sort` table since it has to be the same anyways. This lowers the number of warnings in my SSDT project. Then I just do an `alter` on the column like so:

```
ALTER TABLE #AlterSort ALTER COLUMN [sort] nvarchar(max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: **1)** How much data is returned by `api_utils.GetTable`? **2)** Why call `api_utils.GetTable` twice when the first time the result is dumped into `@Sort`? Wouldn't it be faster to add the `category` and `system` columns to `@Sort` and pull them back in the first call and then use `@Sort` in the `FROM` clause? **3)** Does this have to be a function or can it be a stored procedure?

Comment: @srutzky, I answered these questions in the OP. Thanks!

Comment: **1)** Those 150 records are always from the same source table, correct? **2)** ok. **3)** I was asking about the `api.GetTable` scalar UDF. Can that be turned into a stored proc that uses an output param so the call can at least be similar in nature to calling a UDF?

Comment: **1)** Yes. But sometimes the source table might be different so a different UDF is used. **3)** Yes, I could make it return a OUTPUT param rather than return a table with `JSON`.

Comment: sorry, haven't forgotten...been busy..will post some thoughts tomorrow...(well, later today ;-).

Comment: I was thinking maybe creating a powershell script that looks through my files for anything between `--Start Collate Sort` `--End Collate Sort` and just change the code between there. Then anytime I need to change it I have one place but I still get the performance and cleanness of having the collate in each query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at what you have so far, it's good that `[utils].[OrderByLanguage]` is an Inline Table-Valued Function (ITVF), but it still appears to be a correlated subquery where for each row in `api_utils.GetTable(@LangID)` it passes in all rows in `api_utils.GetTable(@LangID)` to sort it (i.e. the `ORDER BY` clause.

Applying Collations at run-time can be quite costly since it has to generate the sort keys for those values in that moment. For the best performance, creating an index will generate the sort keys ahead of time and even put them in the proper order. But dealing with multiple locales is indeed tricky. Creating a copy of the source column per each locale can require a huge amount of additional disk space (and I/O), depending on the size of the strings, how many locales / Collations one needs, and how many rows there will be over the next 3 - 5 years. Fortunately, you can create non-persisted computed columns to be those copies (which don't take up any space) and index those (which does take up space). While this is likely not feasible if there were 10 locales, a base column of at least `NVARCHAR(200)`, and 1 million (or more) rows, for your situation it should work just fine. With this approach, the dynamic portion will be in choosing which column to select from (achievable via Dynamic SQL, or `IF` statements, depending on the situation). But as you can see with the following example (turn on "Include Actual Execution Plan"), both filtered queries (last 2 queries) get Index Seeks on the intended indexes and return the expected results:

You can see a [live demo of this on dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8957d03eb7def5874a379c81eb932bdc).

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- DROP TABLE #T;
CREATE TABLE #T
(
  [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  [Col1] VARCHAR(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS,
  [Col2] AS ([Col1] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS)
);

CREATE INDEX [IX_#T_Col1] ON [#T] ([Col1]);
CREATE INDEX [IX_#T_Col2] ON [#T] ([Col2]);

INSERT INTO #T ([Col1]) VALUES ('a'), ('A');

SELECT * FROM #T; -- 2 rows

SELECT [ID] FROM #T WHERE [Col1] = 'A'; -- 2 rows

SELECT [ID] FROM #T WHERE [Col2] = 'A'; -- 1 row
```

However, given the code for `api.GetTable` this might not be the best approach. If you wanted to keep the current structure (as much as possible), then you might could do the following:

1. Convert `api.GetTable` into a Stored Procedure
2. Use an `OUTPUT` parameter so you don't need to deal with a result set
3. `@Sort` should be a temporary table, not a table variable
4. Create the `#Sort` temporary table with all of the columns it will need *except* for `[Name]` / `title`): `ID`, `category`, and `[system]`.
5. In a series of `IF` statements, add the `[title]` column, but with the proper Collation:

   ```
   IF (@LanguageID = 2)
   BEGIN
     ALTER TABLE #Sort ADD [title] NVARCHAR(2000) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI
   END;

   IF (@LanguageID = 4)
   BEGIN
     ALTER TABLE #Sort ADD [title] NVARCHAR(2000) COLLATE French_CI_AI
   END;

   ...
   ```
6. Change `FROM api_utils.GetTable(@LangID) t` in the main `@Result=` query to be: `FROM #Sort t`
7. Change `ORDER BY (SELECT s.RowNumber...` in the main `@Result=` query to be: `ORDER BY t.[title]`

This will require re-applying the Collation at each execution, but:

1. it does not require any changes to base tables
2. it will re-use the data returned by `api.GetTable` (no double call)
3. it will use statistics on the `[Name]` column
4. it won't be a correlated sub-query (woo hoo!)
5. it gives you the option of creating an index on the `[Name]` column after it has been populated.

### Code Reuse

By switching over to stored procedures and temporary tables we can actually keep with the goal of code reuse. The code to add the sort column to the local temp table can be abstracted to another stored procedure. While creating a temporary table in a sub-procedure call does not help as that temp table will disappear once that sub-procedure call ends, changes made to a temporary table that exists prior to the sub-procedure call will survive the completion of that call. For example:

**Setup**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #AddSortColumn
(
  @LanguageID TINYINT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @IsColumnAdded BIT = 0;

IF (@LanguageID = 2)
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE #Sort ADD [title] NVARCHAR(2000) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI;
  SET @IsColumnAdded = 1;
END;

IF (@LanguageID = 4)
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE #Sort ADD [title] NVARCHAR(2000) COLLATE French_CI_AI;
  SET @IsColumnAdded = 1;
END;

IF (@IsColumnAdded = 0)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR(N'Invalid @LanguageID: %d', 16, 1, @LanguageID);
  RETURN;
END;
GO
```

**Test**

```
CREATE TABLE #Sort (ID INT);

EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help '#Sort'; -- only 1 column

EXEC #AddSortColumn @LanguageID = 4;

EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help '#Sort'; -- now there are 2 columns
```

By placing the specific Collations only in this one Stored Procedure, you should have only this one place to update when adding a new language to support.

### Putting it all together

With all of the above in mind, we end up with the following stored procedure containing a single call to `api_utils.GetTable()`, no correlated sub-query, *and* `api_utils.AddSortColumn` (which you need to create) can be used in other stored procedures and against other base tables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE api.GetTableAsJSON
(
  @LanguageCode VARCHAR(10),
  @JSONifiedTable NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @LangID TINYINT;

    CREATE TABLE #Sort
    (
      [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      [category] ...,
      [system] ...
    );

    SET @LangID = api_utils.GetLanguageID(@LanguageCode)

    EXEC api_utils.AddSortColumn @LanguageID = @LangID; -- add [Title] to #Sort

    INSERT INTO #Sort ([ID], [category], [system], [Title])
      SELECT t.[ID], t.[category], t.[system], t.[title]
      FROM   api_utils.GetTable(@LangID) t

    -- Optional index; try with and without to see which is better.
    --CREATE INDEX [IX_#Sort_Title] ON #Sort ([Title]);

    SET @JSONifiedTable = (
        SELECT
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.ID) AS [id],
            t.[category],
            t.[system],
            t.title,
            JSON_QUERY(utils.ToRawJsonArray((
                SELECT x.[Description]
                FROM api_utils.GetKeywords(t.[ID], @LangID) x
                ORDER BY x.[Description]
                FOR JSON AUTO), 'Description')
            ) AS [keywords]
        FROM #Sort t
        ORDER BY t.[Title]
        FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('titles')
        );

    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Nice approach, I wouldn't have thought of that! A couple questions. Would having the temp table cause problems for multi threading? Or does the change only affect whatever is on the current thread? I'm not familiar enough w/ SQL Server to know how that works. Also, would it be a good idea to drop the temp table at the end of the procedure? I'm used to programming in F# where everything is pure functions and immutable so I don't normally need to think about these things. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jon49 Local temporary tables ( `#SinglePoundSign` ) are completely confined to the session; they are _not_ visible to other sessions. Global temporary tables ( `##DoublePoundSign` ) are shared across all sessions. Don't worry about dropping at the end. Local Temp objects get cleaned up when the session ends (if created in ad hoc SQL) or when the stored proc in which they were created ends. Global temp objects go away when the session ends (no matter how created), but will live longer if being used by an _active_ query in another session, and will go away when all active references finish.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to just have a code generator. This is if you need max performance as it is only about 14% faster than the solution marked as the answer for my given parameters (Given 14% adds up pretty quickly when you have it in multiple places and in mutliple parts of the same code).

```
# Place the following in your code then run this script and it will update for you
# without the `#` comment symbols. Replace `title` with whatever it field it should
# be sorting by.

#-- Start-Collation-Sort {sort-by:title}
#
#-- End-Collation-Sort

$text = @'
-- Start-Collation-Sort {sort-by:$1,table:$2}
-- This is generated code. Use ./CollationSortGenerator.ps1 to change
-- this code and all the other files which contain this code.
  CASE @LangID
    WHEN 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $2.$1) -- en
    WHEN 3 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $2.$1) -- en-ca
    WHEN 6 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $2.$1) -- 'en-nz'
    WHEN 5 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $2.$1) -- 'en-za'
    WHEN 2 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $2.$1 COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI) -- es
    WHEN 4 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $2.$1 COLLATE French_CI_AI) -- 'fr-ca'
  END
-- `End-Collation-Sort
'@

$regex =
@'
(?m)^\s*-- Start-Collation-Sort {sort-by:(.+),table:(.+)}
[^`]*
-- `End-Collation-Sort
'@

Get-ChildItem -Path *.sql -recurse |
    Where-Object { (Select-String "-- Start-Collation-Sort"  $_ -Quiet -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch) } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Output ("Updating file ... " + ($_ | Resolve-Path -Relative ))

        (Get-Content $_ -Raw) -replace $regex, $text |
        Set-Content $_
    }
```